# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class...could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get all records from "Cours" table where the value of `$speciality` which is submitted by a form is IN the `arrayColloction()` returned by each one single object of class `Cours`. I am using the next lines to have that result (but unfortunately it doesn't work):

```
 public function andWhereSpeciality(QueryBuilder $qb, Speciality $speciality )
  {
    $qb
      ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(':speciality','a.specialities'))
      ->setParameter('speciality', $speciality) ;
    return $qb;
  }
```

The class `Cours` has a `ManyToMany` relation like in the following code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BacUp\GeneralBundle\Entity\Speciality", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Count(min = 1, minMessage = "You have to choose at least one speciality")
 */
private $specialities;
```

The execution returns the following error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class BacUp\GeneralBundle\Entity\Speciality could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr.php line 452" at C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr.php line 452
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue, I post the solution here, it can maybe help somebody else...
You have to use the "MEMBER OF" clause to treat a manytomany relation, and you maybe need to inject the following code directley in the Expr.php file:

```
 /**
 * Creates an instance of MEMBER OF function, with the given arguments.
 *
 * @param string $x Value to be checked
 * @param string $y Value to be checked against
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function isMemberOf($x, $y)
 {
 return $x . ' MEMBER OF ' . $y;
 }
```

For more information, go on [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/400f420925eea9d50eee9ea3d78a847b381865ce) (Maybe you need to use INSTANCE OF also? same way as above)
Now, in my code I used the "isMemberOf" function and that worked fine.

```
public function andWhereSpeciality(QueryBuilder $qb, Speciality $speciality )
  {
    $qb
      ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isMemberOf(':speciality','a.specialities'))
      ->setParameter('speciality', $speciality) ;
    return $qb;
  }
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't test this but using `Member of` should resolve the issue

```
public function andWhereSpeciality(QueryBuilder $qb, Speciality $speciality )
  {
    $qb
      ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isMemberOf(':speciality','a.specialities'))
      ->setParameter('speciality', $speciality) ;
    return $qb;
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception now: [code]CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted to call method "isMemberOf" on class "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr" in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\BacUp\GeneralBundle\Entity\CoursRepository.php line 84." at C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\BacUp\GeneralBundle\Entity\CoursRepository.php line 84 [/code]